# Javascript: Insert text at specified line

Tags: javascript, mirth

I am kind of new to javascript, but I was looking to see if it was possible to add a line of text to a file at a specified position?   i.e.  every file needs to have the same text inserted at line no. 3

Someone suggested "split by line feed, add data, then rejoin", but i have no clue how to do that.   Just looking for somewhere to get started or pointed in the right diretion.

Comment: I don't think JS is the language you're looking for.  I know this can be done with easy in Python

Comment: Do you load the file via Ajax, and store it via a server-side script?

Comment: SomeKittens is right, javascript doesn't really work with files if you want to resave them.

Comment: Actually, I am reading files into a program called Mirth, which uses java/javascript

Answer (score 2):

Split by line feed:

```
data = data.split(/\r?\n/);
```

Add data:

```
data = data.splice(2, 0, new_data);
```

Rejoin:

```
data = data.join("\r\n");
```

Comment: JavaScript has a `splice` method for inserting new elements at a specific index: `data.splice( 2, 0, new_data );`